# TypeScript overload: string or custom object as function argument and return type

Tags: typescript, overloading, typescript-typings

I'm trying to overload a function in TypeScript.

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Returns a 400 Bad Request error.
 *
 * @returns A response with the 400 status code and a message.
 */
export function badRequest(): TypedResponse<{ message: string }>;
/**
 * Returns a 400 Bad Request error.
 *
 * @param errors - An object containing the errors from the Zod schema.
 * @returns A response with the 400 status code, a message and the errors.
 */
export function badRequest<T>(
  errors: ZodFormattedError<T>,
): TypedResponse<{ message: string; errors: ZodFormattedError<T> }>;
/**
 * Returns a 400 Bad Request error.
 *
 * @param errors - An error string.
 * @returns A response with the 400 status code, a message and the errors.
 */
export function badRequest(
  errors: string,
): TypedResponse<{ message: string; errors: string }>;
export function badRequest<T>(errors?: ZodFormattedError<T> | string) {
  return json(
    { message: 'Bad Request', ...(errors && { errors }) },
    { status: 400 },
  );
}

const myRequest = badRequest({
  _errors: [
    {
      code: 'invalid_type',
      expected: 'string',
      received: 'number',
      path: ['name'],
      message: 'Expected string, received number',
    },
  ],
});
```

I want TypeScript to know, that when `badRequest` is called without any arguments, the return type only has a message, and when it is called with a string, it should have a property `errors` that contains a string and when it is called with a `ZodFormattedError` the `errors` property should be those errors.

I tried the code above, and TypeScript yells:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(errors: ZodFormattedError<{ _errors: unknown; }, string>): TypedResponse<{ message: string; errors: ZodFormattedError<{ _errors: unknown; }, string>; }>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ code: string; expected: string; received: string; path: string[]; message: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(errors: string): TypedResponse<{ message: string; errors: string; }>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ _errors: { code: string; expected: string; received: string; path: string[]; message: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

How can I correctly overload this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it with these overloads:

```
/**
 * Returns a 400 Bad Request error.
 *
 * @returns A response with the 400 status code and a message.
 */
export function badRequest(): TypedResponse<{ message: string }>;
/**
 * Returns a 400 Bad Request error.
 *
 * @param errors - An object containing the errors from the Zod schema.
 * @returns A response with the 400 status code, a message and the errors.
 */
export function badRequest<T>(
  errors?: ZodFormattedError<T>,
): TypedResponse<{ message: string; errors: ZodFormattedError<T> }>;
/**
 * Returns a 400 Bad Request error.
 *
 * @param errors - A string containing the errors.
 * @returns A response with the 400 status code, a message and the errors.
 */
export function badRequest(
  errors?: string,
): TypedResponse<{ message: string; errors: string }>;
export function badRequest<T>(
  errors?: ZodFormattedError<T> | string,
): TypedResponse<{ message: string; errors?: ZodFormattedError<T> | string }> {
  return json(
    { message: 'Bad Request', ...(errors && { errors }) },
    { status: 400 },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer**

Based on the official docs, typescript supports function overloading. Thanks Hesters for the [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).

Issue in your code is with the type of parameters for which you have overloaded the function and with those you are trying to call.

Based on the implementation, badRequest method can be called with **no parameters**, **string** type, **ZodFormatter** type. But you are trying to call it with a **list of ZodFormatter** type which is causing the issue.

[image]

In the above code snippet, method is overloaded with no parameters, string type, number type and when called with a list of numbers type (which is not declared) it throws an error. When called with correct arguments, it runs successfully.

[image]

Comment: Hi Shanmukha, thanks for the help. Unfortunately, this doesn't fix the error. When I add `export function badRequest(
  errors: undefined,
): TypedResponse<{ message: string }>;` the error still persists.

Comment: Also, the official TypeScript docs explicitly show examples where overloads have different number of arguments: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads

Comment: Thanks for the docs. In your code, you have provided an implementation to the functions which either accept string nor ZodFormattedError<T> but you are trying to call the function with a list of ZodFormattedError<T>. Can you try either changing the declaration or the usage of it ?

Comment: Hi Shanmukha,

Unfortunately, that's not it either. The `ZodFormattedError` type has a `key` called `errors_`, which can be an array of strings.

Comment: Changing the return statement to `return { message: "", ...(errors && { errors }), status: 400};` works fine. Sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/9u269w?file=/index.ts) for the same

Comment: Thanks a lot for creating the code sandbox! The `ZodFormattedError` type comes from a package called `zod`. `json` comes from Remix (`@remix-run/node`). If you install those packages and import the types in your code sandbox, it breaks, too.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you really mean for the second signature should be:

```
export function badRequest<T extends<any, any>>(
  errors: T,
): TypedResponse<{ message: string; errors: T }>;
```

This makes your TS error go away.

Note that the original `ZodFormattedError<T, U=string>` interface has its second type param default to `string`. You have to explicitly provide a type value in that second position, so to override the default value. Here I just use `any`, change it if you want more specific constraint.